# Containers run well independently but not in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an app with separated frontend and backend, each one is a subfolder. I have dockerized the front and the back separately in their folders, respectively.

Now, I'm trying to run them in the same network by using docker-compose in the root folder. The build is done successfully, but when I run it, the front container works just fine, but the back container exits with code 0.

Maybe it's worth mentioning that the container of the back is a done with a docker-compose too.

Can you help me please?

Here's how the docker-compose.yml looks like in the root folder

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  back:
    build: ./backend/
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
  front:
    build: ./frontend/
    ports:
        - "80:3000"
```

output:

```
app_back_1 exited with code 0
front_1  | INFO: Accepting connections at http://localhost:3000.
```

Here's the docker-compose file of the backend:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
    app:
        build:
            context: .
        command: gunicorn backend.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - static_data:/vol/static
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        restart: always
        env_file:
            - .env
        depends_on:
            - app-db

    app-db:
        image: postgres:12-alpine
        ports:
            -  "5432:5432"
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
        env_file:
            - .env
    proxy:
        build: ./proxy
        volumes:
            - static_data:/vol/static
            - media_data:/vol/media
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8008:80"
        depends_on:
            - app
volumes:
    static_data:
    media_data:
    postgres_data:
```

Comment: What is the second `docker-compose.yml` file; how do you run it?  What is in `./backend/Dockerfile`?  (One Compose file can't launch another.)

Answer (score 0):

If the container runs well, It should run well with identical docker image that you have built. Try `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate --no-deps` to recreate everything from scratch with no cache, so then if you have error in your source code the error will throw for both standalone container and compose.

Comment: This does not solve the issue. I have the same log : `back exited with code 0`
Maybe this has to do with volumes ?

Comment: Does this error occurs for both compose and cli ? can you share your cli command for starting the container ?

Comment: If I want to start the back container alone I use `docker-compuse up` in its folder.

When I want to run the front and the back simultaneously, I run `docker-compose up` in the root directory

Comment: Can you share the directory tree view along with docker entrypoints for the backend container ?

Comment: Your API returning exit code 0 just means that the HTTP response was empty (no headers returned) and your application was shut down gracefully. 

This could be a number of things I.e CORS Error, Firewall Block, Code Cancelled Request. Please provide your Dockerfile so we can get a bit more context on what you are trying to run

Comment: I edited the post by adding the docker-compose file of the backend.

Thank you so much for trying to help btw.